# How to show data labels on ggplot (geom_point) in R using Power BI?

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to do a geom_point chart in Power BI, using R. It's showing results of 2 different tests. I want the **color of the dots** by gender and the **data labels** to be name of the person.

This is my code:

```
na_strings <- c("Not Provided", "Decline To Self Identify")
dataset <- dataset %>% replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.x %in% na_strings) 

dataset$gender <- as.factor(dataset$gender)
dataset$`Candidate Full Name` <- as.factor(dataset$`Candidate Full Name`)

#chart:
ggplot(data = subset(dataset, !is.na(`gender`)), aes(x=`Numerical`, y= `Verbal`,  col = gender )) +
  geom_text(aes(label=`Candidate Full Name`), data=subset(dataset, !is.na(`gender`)), hjust=0, vjust=0, check_overlap = TRUE)+
  geom_point()
```

However what I get instead of gender and Candidate Full Name is the numbers:
[image: chart]

The exported data directly from the visual in Power BI looks like this:
[image: csv]

Any idea why and how to overcome this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what do the numbers represent? can you `head` the data set? I am suspecting that your data mapping is wrong...

Comment: Ok, that's tricky.. how can I head the data, if it's based on an existing data in Power BI (I didin't import anything from R directly) I don't have a query linked to this data, and writing head(dataset) doesn't return anything.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why R behaves differently when making a Power BI visual, but I've confirmed the same problem on my machine. It seems related to the **replace_with_na_all** function. The problem went away when I replaced that line as below.

```
# dataset <- dataset %>% replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.x %in% na_strings)
dataset[dataset$gender %in% na_strings,"gender"] <- NA_character_
```